# Nested Attributes not saving to Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested-attributes

I've been Stack Overflowing for a while now, and I've done some tutorials/walkthroughs across the web including RailsGuides & Railscasts, but I seem to be having trouble saving my nested attributes to my database.

I have Wagers, which have many Terms

```
class Wager < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :host,  class_name: "User", foreign_key: "host_id"
  belongs_to :guest,  class_name: "User", foreign_key: "guest_id"  
  has_many :terms, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :terms, allow_destroy: true , :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:terms].blank?  }

  attr_accessible :title, :description, :terms, :terms_attributes

end
```

And Terms

```
class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :wager
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :criterion, :host_criterion, :guest_criterion, :terms_attributes
end
```

My Wagers controller

```
class WagersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index

  end

  def create
    # Create new wager from params
    @wager = Wager.new(params[:wager])
    # Assign current user 
    @wager.host_id = current_user.id
    # Assign guest user here
    # ______________________
    @term = @wager.terms.build(params[:terms])

    if @wager.valid? 
      respond_to do |format|
        if @wager.save
          format.html { redirect_to(@wager, :notice => 'Wager Stub successfully created.') }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @wager, :status => :created, :location => @wager }
        else
          format.html { render :action => "new" }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @wager.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
     end

  def new
    @wager = Wager.new
    @term = Term.new
    3.times { @wager.terms.build }
  end  
end
```

My new view:

```
<h2>Create a Wager</h2>

<%= form_for @wager, url: {action: "create"}, html: {class: ""} do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Create a wager</legend>

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
    <label>Title</label>
        <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "The Bet To End All Bets" %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        <label>With</label>
            <%#= f.text_field :guest, placeholder: "Choose a Friend" %> 
    </div>
    <div class="large-8 columns">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
    <label>Description</label>
    <%= f.text_area :description, size: "60x12", placeholder: "What's all this about?" %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">  
    <div class="large-5 columns">
    <div class="row collapse">
      <h4>Your Terms</h4>
            </div>

      <%= f.fields_for :terms do |term_form| %>
        <%= term_form.label :host_criterion, 'Term:' %>
        <%= term_form.text_field :host_criterion %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

  <div class="large-5 columns">
    <div class="row collapse">
      <h4>Their Terms</h4>
    </div>

    <%= f.fields_for :terms do |term_form| %>
      <%= term_form.label :guest_criterion, 'Term:' %>
      <%= term_form.text_field :guest_criterion %>
    <% end %>  
  </div>

  </div>


<div class="row">
<div class="large-8 columns">
</div>
<div class="large-4 columns">
    <%= f.submit "Create Stub", class: "button" %>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

My params look like this: (SPOILER ALERT: They're all nil. Except it does assign a wager ID. Pretty sure that's due to the build method)

```
=> 
"wager"=>
 {"title"=>"Title of the Bet",
  "description"=>"Bet description",
 "terms_attributes"=>
   {"0"=>{"host_criterion"=>"You gotta be nude"},
    "1"=>{"host_criterion"=>"no drinking"},
    "2"=>{"host_criterion"=>"can't brush your hair"},
    "3"=>{"guest_criterion"=>"Guest Term 1"},
    "4"=>{"guest_criterion"=>"Guest Term 2"},
    "5"=>{"guest_criterion"=>"Guest Term 3"}}},
    "commit"=>"Create Stub",
    "action"=>"create",
    "controller"=>"wagers"}
```

Yet when the record is saved, my server log says:

```
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
(0.6ms)  begin transaction
SQL (1.9ms)  INSERT INTO "wagers" ("created_at", "deadline", "description", "guest_id", "host_id", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 17 Oct 2013 23:50:50 UTC +00:00], ["deadline", nil], ["description", "Bet description"], ["guest_id", nil], ["host_id", 5], ["title", "Title of the Bet"], ["updated_at", Thu, 17 Oct 2013 23:50:50 UTC +00:00]]
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "terms" ("created_at", "criterion", "guest_criterion", "host_criterion", "updated_at", "wager_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 17 Oct 2013 23:50:50 UTC +00:00], ["criterion", nil], ["guest_criterion", nil], ["host_criterion", nil], ["updated_at", Thu, 17 Oct 2013 23:50:50 UTC +00:00], ["wager_id", 48]]
(1.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/wagers/48
Completed 302 Found in 121668ms (ActiveRecord: 5.9ms)
```

What am I missing? The goal is to create a term for each of the terms (up to 6) submitted along with the wager. I'd appreciate any help on this as the walkthroughs I've found online have all for the most part led me to this point, but it just ends up working for them (Rails sugar style), validations and all. :-/

Running Rails 3.2.13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:terms].blank?  }` is stopping it from working.

Instead, it should be: `reject_if: lambda { |terms| terms[:host_criterion].blank? }`
*NOTE: I replaced "a" with "terms" for clarity*

The issue with the first one is rails will look for a field called "terms" in the "terms" table.  Instead, it should be looking for "host_criterion".

The [revised railscast](https://github.com/railscasts/196-nested-model-form-part-1) removed this method altogether and uses coffeescript to validate do this on the client side (prevent empty records in the terms table).

Comment: Thanks Ira! The host terms now save. I'm working right now on getting the guest ones to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the @term for they_terms thing. try it and let me know if it works.

or better would create a new relationshipt for their_terms using the terms table.